# Two synonyms each of Saxon and French origin where the Saxon word is "classier"

Tags: loanwords, french, class-based-usage

To clarify the title, i am looking for two words in the English vocabulary. Normally in English words of French origin are seen as fancier and used by intelligent and upper class people. But is there any event of two words where one is of Anglo-Saxon origins and the other of French origin in which the Anglo-Saxon one is generally seen as more "fancy"?

Note that this excludes words of German origin borrowed during the 1700s and 1800s and etc.

Comment: As a euphemism for *syphilis*, I have always found "the French disease" to be far classier than "the English disease."

Comment: @Mick That doesn't work. *Syphilis* is Latin and one assumes arrived in English through French. *Pox* on the other hand is Germanic - so it follows the usual rule.

Comment: @WS2 I knew that there was a fault in my logic somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

"Flower" is Romance, while "blossom" is Germanic. I don't know if there's a huge difference of "classiness" between them, but the first is definitely a more everyday word than the second.

Comment: Quite true, the word _bloom_ also sounds 'posher' than _flower_ (unless you're a steelworker)!

Answer (score 6):

["Victuals"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=victuals) is derived from Old French, and on the face of it seems like the "classiest" possible way to say "sustenance"... but in everyday usage, it's pronounced "vittles" - and [often spelled that way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tender_Vittles).  I think you could make a stong case that ["food"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=food) is classier than "vittles".

Comment: In Norfolk, years ago, old people used to say *wittles*. But you are spot-on here, I would suggest. Well done.

Comment: I love the Aubrey/Maturin books, so my first association is Killick saying "Wittles is up, if you please, sir."

Comment: @M T Head It seems to me that "viands" is closer to "victuals" than "sustenance," but I like your answer in part because it shows that reasonable people can agree that some words are "classy." "Classy" may be a matter of opinion, but as Justice Stevens pointed out, so is pornography. The question posed is interesting. I wish I had the clout to spring it from the hold.

Answer (score 6):

[**color**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/colour) -  From Anglo-Norman colur, from Old French colour, color, from Latin color, from Old Latin colos ‎(“covering”), from Proto-Indo-European *ḱel- ‎(“to cover, conceal”).

[**hue**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hue)  - (meaning a colour or shade) From Middle English hewe, from Old English hīew, hīw ‎(“appearance, form, species, kind; apparition; hue, color; beauty; figure of speech”), from Proto-Germanic *hiwją ‎(“hue, form, shape, appearance; mildew”)